# Copy Unstructured data into HDFS?

Tags: hadoop

How to copy unstructured data directly from web server to HDFS using Sqoop in Hadoop. (without copying data into the local file system)

Answer (score 1):

From webserver to HDFS you need to use Flume or anyother appropriate tool. Sqoop is used to import/export from RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have said the source to be Webserver and data to be unstructured, **Flume** is what you should look for!!

> Flume is a distributed, reliable, and available service for
>   efficiently collecting, aggregating, and moving large amounts of log
>   data

http://flume.apache.org/

If data source is RDBMS and data is structured, then Sqoop will fit the bill.

> Sqoop is designed for efficiently transferring bulk data between
>   Apache Hadoop and structured datastores such as relational databases.

http://sqoop.apache.org/